# More flexibility with background position?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'd like to move the t-shirt picture (currently positioned bottom-left) a little bit further to the right (approx 40 pixels). How could I achieve this? I tried to set a padding right of 40px to the body of the page when then the whole content moves which is not something I want. Many thanks

[image]

```
Html, body {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;;
    min-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(pics/T-shirt.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left bottom
```

Comment: you'll need to play around with background-position attribute.  Set it to background-position:0px 0px; and change the values until you get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `background-position: x y;` using % or pixels.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
background-position:40px bottom
```